# plotly round decimals and add commas in figure_factory tables

Tags: python, plotly

I've created a table in pandas and would like to display it with plotly. However I want to do my number formatting with plotly instead of pandas.

How can I do this?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.figure_factory as ff

df = pd.DataFrame({'num': [1, 2, 3],
                   'sqrt': pd.Series([1, 2, 3]) ** 0.5,
                  'exp': np.exp2(pd.Series([10, 11, 12]))})
fig = ff.create_table(df)
fig.show()
```

This shows
[image: current format]

What can I change to get
[image: desired format]

Answer (score 2):

I tried to update the annotations for figure_factory because the table contents are text, but an error occurred, so I used a graph object. The format can be set in the cells of the graph object, so specify it there. However, to change the display format for each individual cell, you need to list the appropriate format for each individual cell.
I also changed the row colors, etc. to match the decorations in figure_factory.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

fmt = np.array(['.2f' if len(str(v)) == 18 else None for v in df.values.T.flatten()]).reshape(3,3)

headerColor = 'midnightblue'
rowEvenColor = 'ghostwhite'
rowOddColor = 'whitesmoke'

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Table(
    header=dict(
        values=[['<b>{}</b>'.format(h)] for h in df.columns],
        fill_color=headerColor,
        line_color='darkslategray',
        font=dict(color='white', size=12),
    ),
    cells=dict(
        values=df.values.T,
        format=fmt,
        fill_color = [[rowOddColor,rowEvenColor,rowOddColor]*3],
        height=25
    ))
                     ])
fig.show()
```

[image]